# Count only if field is filled

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about a SQL query I want to write. Suppose I have a column with the follow values in table: school with column: grades.

```
 SUI grades | Score
  2  9          2
  2  9          
  5  4          1
  5  4          1
  5  4
  6  1          1
  6  1
```

Now I want an output where it groups the SUI that counts grades only if Score is filled. So my output will be:

```
SUI Count 
 2    1
 5    2
 6    1
```

Comment: Don't you mean 5 2 instead of 4 2 in the expected result?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: count(columnname) counts non-null values!

Comment: Yes is mean a 5 instead of 4

Comment: But is `score` declared to be `NULL` (versus `NOT NULL`) _and_ are not seeing an empty string `''`?

Comment: If you are getting counts of 2,3,2, then you have empty strings, not NULLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are just blank and NOT NULL you can use function <> ''
It will only count those field that have values in them

```
SELECT SUI, Count(Grades)
FROM mytable 
WHERE Score <> ''
GROUP BY SUI
```

Answer (score 1):

I would filter before aggregating:

```
SELECT sui, COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE score IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY sui;
```

Comment: What about the grades column?

Comment: @the_boy_za . . . It is not `NULL`, so `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(grades)` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`count` ignores nulls, so you could use a `having` condition:

```
SELECT   sui, COUNT(score)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY sui
HAVING   COUNT(score) > 0
```

Comment: The problem is that score is a varchar. IT can also filled with words

Comment: @the_boy_za that shouldn't be an issue - you're just counting the number of rows it exists, not performing any math on it (unlike, e.g., `sum`))